# Can differentiate Application Cache if mutiple application offline on Chrome Android 5?

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching

Guys

Whether there is few application can go offline on Chrome Android 5.1, can we differentiate the application cache for every application, and delete them seperately?

I saw there is native interface we can use to delete cache, such as get webStorage instance to delete Chrome cache. So can we delete the cache application level?

Comment: please explain one scenario , then it will become more clear

Comment: thanks for your reply, just like Application A can go offline with Chrome Android, and Application B/C/D... also can go offline, so application cache offline mode also contains A/B/C/D...., but we only want to delete 1 of them, such as only delete application A's offline cache.